# customizing html templating in bootstrap tags

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tags

I'm taking a looking at bootstrap tags found here: http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

I'd like to be able to hook into the HTML that's being rendered to add additional anchors/links to the tags being generated. There is an event named: `beforeItemAdd()` that allows you to see the item before it's added, but you can't necessarily interact with it other than prevent it from being rendered.

Is there a way to customize the HTML output here so I can add additional links besides the 'x' to my tag? Just applying a CSS class won't work, I need to be able to modify the actual markup being rendered so I can add content to the tags.

Alternatively, I'm open to a solution with tagging that allows for the customizing of tag HTML rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging really deep into the plugin source ( I've never used this plugin), or figuring out what data is stored,  one way would be to use `this` in the event callback to traverse to the main container the plugin wraps everything in and then find the tag elements.

Add a class each time and then you know what you have already modified and the one without that class would be your new one

```
$('input').on('itemAdded', function(event) {
  var $cont = $(this).siblings('.bootstrap-tagsinput'),
      $tag = $cont.find('.tag').not('.modified').addClass('modified');
      $tag.doSomeStuff();      
});
```

Comment: This seems to grab the entire select and not the actual tag we need to modify. I see what you're getting at, though. Looks like it'll require some hack regardless.

Comment: Create a live demo in jsfiddle or other sandbox. I just didn't feel like sorting out dependencies needed to create one myself. Also not sure what configuration you are using

Comment: jsfiddle available here: https://jsfiddle.net/t4v5k501/  I'm trying to add another `span` in each tag so a sibling to `<span data-role="remove"></span>` could be `<span data-role="foo">bar</span>`

Comment: ok..I misread tree hierarchy (or it's different for select), should be `var $cont = $(this).siblings('.bootstrap-tagsinput')`